# How to delete a folder in a directory in QTreeview?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, signals-slots, qtreeview

I'm creating a application for my project,

My scenario is : I choose the Directory and it show Tree Folder in QTreeview, after that I will click right on folder, it show "Delete" menu. And when i push it, my folder which i chose will be delete.

Everything is fine till I right click on QTreeview, my application turn off intermediately. And errors :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/Library/test.py",
>   line 114, in showMenu
>       self.delete.connect(self.removeButton()) TypeError: PySide.QtCore.QObject.connect(): not enough arguments

This is my code :

```
def showMenu(self, pos):
    menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
    self.delete = QtGui.QAction("Delete",menu)
    menu.addAction(self.newfolder)
    menu.popup(self.folders_lv.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos))
    self.delete.connect(self.removeButton())

def removeButton(self):
    self.deleteLater()
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

You are not connecting the signal correctly. A `QAction` has [several signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#signals), and you need to connect one of them to a method or function. So to connect the `triggered` signal to the `removeButton` method, do this:

```
    self.delete.triggered.connect(self.removeButton)
```

Comment: I try with your code, but when i click delete, all my application is turned off. I just want to delete the folder I choose, could you help me ?

Comment: @MinhTuanNguyen. I gave you a fix for the error in your question, which was about connecting signals. I'm sorry, but I cannot write your whole application for you. I assume from some of your other questions, that you are using `QFileSystemModel`. Please read the [documentation for it](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html) and try to understand how it works, so that you can ask better questions.